# Use a different setParameters.xml file?

Tags: msdeploy

So I've got my deploy working on a build and I've set up my build to create a deployment package and execute the package on the target server. Great so far.
Now however the application is expanding and I need to have different configurations per machine (account names and such like),

Can I specify what the file name of "setParameters.xml" for example to "Server1.SetParameters.xml" or similar ?

I've got it copying the files over the SetParameters.xml before each deploy for now but is seems in-elegant and should a file get locked for what ever the reason it would deploy the wrong settings to the wrong server.

Comment: Are you using msdeploy.exe yourself or are you using the Visual Studio integration (ie. Web Publishing Pipeline)?

Comment: I'm using the package that MsBuild Creates using the `/p:DeployOnBuild=true` and `/p:DeployTarget=Package` I'm then executing the package in the `AfterDropBuild` target using exec and a file path like `_PublishedWebsites\Website_Package\Website.deploy.cmd /Y /M:Server1 /U:User /P:Password`

Which I think is the second option but if using msdeploy directly I'm happy to switch.

Comment: Hi @MarkBroadhurst can you share how did you copy/generate multiple setparameters.xml files?

Comment: @Bat_Programmer As I commented on the answer I used the following cmd `Website.deploy.cmd /Y /M:Server1 /U:User /P:Pass -setParamFile:Server1.SetParameters.xml`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since you are using the WPP-generated *deploy.cmd* file, the simplest choice is to set `%_DeploySetParametersFile%` to a full path to your setParmeters file before you execute the deploy script.

```
SET _DeploySetParametersFile=c:\full\path\to\setParmaeters.xml
call Website.deploy.cmd
```

Alternatively, if you want to use msdeploy directly, you can specify `-setParamFile:c:\full\path\to\setParmaeters.xml`. For more information, see [Web Deploy Operation Settings](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569089%28v=ws.10%29)

Comment: I got it working with the following command `Website.deploy.cmd /Y /M:Server1 /U:User /P:Pass -setParamFile:Server1.SetParameters.xml` Thank you